# Problem creating my first database , annoying error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created two tables:

- `person` (`id` as pk , `person` and `purchase`)
- `user` (`id` as pk , other columns not relevant to question).

After linking the two with an n:m relationship, and proceeding to forward engineer (I'm using MySql Workbench), I get this error:

> Error:  Executing SQL script in server
>
> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' INDEX
>   fk_table1_has_user_table1_idx (table1_id ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT' at
>   line 8

Note: I'm following a tutorial. As far as I can tell, my code's the exact same as what's in the tutorial, and the tutorial guy didn't get an error.

SQL Code:

```
-- Table mydb.table1_has_user -- 
-----------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.table1_has_user
      ( table1_id INT NOT NULL,
        user_user id INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (table1_id, user_user id),
        INDEX fk_table1_has_user_user1_idx (user_user id ASC) VISIBLE,
        INDEX fk_table1_has_user_table1_idx (table1_id ASC) VISIBLE,
        CONSTRAINT fk_table1_has_user_table1 FOREIGN KEY (table1_id)
            REFERENCES mydb.table1 (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
        CONSTRAINT fk_table1_has_user_user1 FOREIGN KEY (user_user id) 
            REFERENCES mydb.user (user id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
     ) ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Can someone please help me with this? I don't know what I'm doing wrong , the primary key is correct why is this happening?

This is the diagram of the database I'm trying to create:
[image: this is the model image]

Comment: I removed the relation between the two tables and the code ran correctly , only after running the relation does the program bug out.

Comment: Based on the code you posted, there were 8 SQL statements you tried to execute, and 7 of them executed successfully. Since you say you can create this table if you leave out the foreign key constraints, that's probably where the problem is. Are you sure you've named the the columns in those constraints the same as the names in the actual other tables?

Comment: In particular, I note the `user id` column from the `user` table. A column name with a space in it is unusual; it has to be quoted ( `\`user id\`` ) to work correctly. Is the column name quoted in the `user` table definition, or is it possibly `user_id` instead?

Answer (score 4):

The keyword `VISIBLE` is a MySQL-8.0 syntax. If you are using an earlier version, or MariaDB, omit this word.

Comment: In fact, MySQL Workbench is made for MySQL and nothing else.

Comment: I assume it would be better if MySQL Workbench put `VISIBLE` in a versioned comment to ensure it works on earlier server versions. I think the same syntax error has occured here before.

Comment: A Workbench model comes with a MySQL version, which dictates the used language features. If that doesn't work as expected it's a bug.

Comment: Great that works. Thanks @danblack! Since visible is default, I don't understand why workbench would use it but hey.. happy it works now :)